# How to using C# convert List<int> to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Below is a sample:

```
List<int> list=new List<int>(){1,2,3};

XElement XML=new XElement(/*...*/);

Console.WriteLine("print:"+XML);
```

Expected result:

`//print:<root><item>1</item><item>2</item><item>3</item></root>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
            var document = new XDocument(new XElement("root",  list.Select(x => new XElement("item", x))));
            Console.WriteLine("print:" + document);
        }
    }
}
```